# Laravel 5.3 - how to just get the token from the "forgot password" functionality?

Tags: laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.3, I'm aware of how to change the content of the default password reset email, but that's not the route I want to go down. Our app sends all emails through Mailjet templates, and we have a specifit trait set up so it's easy enough to chuck the emails down that route. To keep things structured, therefore, I want the password reset functionality to operate along the same lines.

All I need to do is to get the token, and just the token, out of the multitude of methods that appear to be involved in resetting the password, and I can then generate the email and link separately and send it through Mailjet.

Any pointers that anyone can give will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The token you are talking about is generated when the user fills the "Forgot Password" field.

The tokens are in the `password_resets` database table. In that table, you will see the user's `email` and `token`. The token you want to get is the token there.

To get the token, you could do this query:

```
$pw_reset = \DB::table('password_resets')->where('email', $user->email)->first();
```

Now, you can simply do `$pw_reset->token` to get the user's token. Make sure that there is a record in your table or else you will get an exception. You can do this by replacing the `->first()` above with `->firstOrFail()`

That is how you would get the password reset token.

---

**Generating the Token without having the user to request a password reset email**

I you don't want the user to fill the "Forgot Password" field and request an email and then fetch the token, you can manually create a token.

```
$user = User::find(1) // Get the user with an ID of 1. This can be any user ID

$pw_reset = DB::table('password_resets')->insert(
    ['email' => $user->email, 'token' => str_random(255)]
);
```

You will have inserted your user token in database and can fetch the recently stored token using `$pw_reset->token`.

There you go. I gave you **2 ways** to **store** the tokens in database and **one** way to **retrieve** the token from database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - both are kind of close to what I'm hoping to achieve, but neither hit it actually on the nose.

Comment: Sorry - didn't realise it'll submit when I press return.

To clarify, I want them to have to fill in a form to get a password reset email, I want them to use the built-in forgot password functionality, and I want Laravel to generate the code and save it in the DB. What I don't want, though, is for Laravel to send its bog standard email and I want to have it pass the relevant values (user, token, etc.) to our site-wide Mailjet sending function. 

Does that clarify it a little?

Comment: To follow up on this, I've ended up going more down your second route, and simply bypassing Laravel's password reset functionality, instead just using a function to populate the password reset table with a value I generate, rather than picking apart Laravel's methodology - I've accepted your answer, as without it I wouldn't have considered(!) just setting the password reset token myself.